# How do I know if a user navigates away from my android app java?

Tags: android

I have multiple activities in my android app. I would like to log it when a user navigates away from and back to my application. I cannot do this in onResume() and onPause() in the activities because I wouldn't know if my user is navigating away or simply launching another activity.

Is there a place at application level for me to know if a user navigates away from and back to my application?

Comment: isn't launching another activity considered as navigating away?

Comment: Use your own [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only for API level 14 and above**

You can implement [ComponentCallbacks2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) to an `activity`, `service`, etc.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ComponentCallbacks2 {
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onLowMemory() {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTrimMemory(final int level) {
     if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
        // app is in background
     }
   }
}
```

Hope this would help you out.